# Non blocking loop through binary buffer and push to socket

Tags: javascript, sockets, asynchronous, google-chrome-app

I am uploading a file to ftp via chrome.sockets but the socket buffer size is limited, so i need to loop through the blob and send out smaller chunks of data. I have tried several methods with closures and callbacks but the only way working for me is do/while loop, which is of course blocking. Part of the problem is multiple variables that need to be kept in the closure. Can you please suggest better way of looping through the blob?

```
do
{
    chunk = blob.slice(start,end)
    start =end
    end =end + 8192
    chrome.socket.write(this.info.socketId, Socket.string2buffer(chunk), function(writeInfo) {});
}
while (chunk.length>0);
```

Complete code of the extension (single purpose ftp manager) https://github.com/vanous/minime-content-manager/tree/master/chromium-ext-broadcast

Comment: See chrome.sockets, which is a newer version of this API that is currently dev-channel-only.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something along the lines of the following should work:

```
var self=this;
var writeChunk=function(start,end){
    var chunk = blob.slice(start,end);
    chrome.socket.write(self.info.socketId, Socket.string2buffer(chunk), function(writeInfo) {
        if(chunk.length>0) writeChunk(end,end+8192);
    });
};
writeChunk(0,8192);
```